# How do I add a space to an existing String?

Tags: java, string, loops, addition, space

I created a console project which is a simple game of hangman. Here is what I have done so far...

```
static String answer;
static String display = "";
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("please enter the word or phrase to be guessed");
    answer = input.next();
    System.out.print("Please make a guess: ");
    //loop to check each character in the string
    for(int i = 0; i < answer.length(); i++){
        if(answer.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            //adds an underscore to the String that will be printed
            display += "_";
        }//end if
        else {
            //adds a space to the String that will be printed
            display += " ";
        }//end else
    }//end for
    System.out.print(display);
}
```

What I'm trying to is to go through some text that the user inputs and print an underscore in the case of a letter and otherwise make a space.

1. Sample input: *I like dogs*
2. Sample output: *Please make a guess: _ ____ ____*

I think i am going about adding a space to the String in the wrong way and can't find anyone with the same problem.

What is actually happening is shown below,

1. Sample input: *I like Dogs*
2. Sample output: *Please make a guess: _*
3. Sample input: *this is broken*
4. Sample output: *Please make a guess: ____*

What it is doing is printing the right amount underscores until it encounters the first space and then it stops.

Comment: What's the type of `input`? `Scanner`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input.next()` only reads until the first space ' '. If you want to read a whole line you need to use `input.nextLine()`

Comment: Thank you so much, now that you say that I just realized I encountered the problem before in a different situation but I was blindly believing my input method was correct